# "В каждой — тонна..." Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Две зверюги, размером со льва.
>   В каждой — тонна отборного веса...

Comment: Отборное мясо — понимаю, отборный вес — нЭ понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Тире ставится в неполном предложении**. В данном случае опущено «из них».

Вообще говоря, в неполных предложениях тире ставится не всегда, но здесь желательно обозначить паузу и для понимания смысла, и для выразительности стиха.

Answer (score 2):

*Две зверюги, размером со льва.

В каждой — тонна отборного веса...*

Думаю, что тире вполне к месту, оно оправдано и структурой предложения, и правилами.
[**Тире в неполном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93)

*На свете миллион таких городишек. И в каждом также темно, так же одиноко, каждый так же от всего отрешен, в каждом — свои ужасы и свои тайны.*
Р. Брэдбери. Вино из одуванчиков

P.S. Ваши зверюги львиного размера весят по тонне. ТАК не может быть! Максимальный [**вес льва**](http://wikimassa.org/skolko_vesit_lev) — 300 кг.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! На счет веса, текст не мой, и это не львы, а *зверюги* :)